# Why all OS X verions are 10?

Tags: macos, history

I was looking at the [versions section of Wikipedia's article for OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X#Versions) and I realized that all versions are prefixed with 10. Why? What is the logic behind prefixing al versions with a number that never changes?

Does it have to do something with the X in OS X? Why is it OS X? Is there some kind of fanaticism over the number 10 at Apple?

Comment: Because `X` == 10 (roman numeral).

Answer (score 2):

OS X is supposed to be pronounced "Oh Ess Ten" though no-one outside Apple ever seems to, common parlance would be "oss ex".

Though OS XI would, I guess, be OS eleven, how many people are going to end up calling it "oss exie" or "oss ex eye"?

The actual answer to the question "Why?" is presumably because Steve Jobs decided it would be; & that would brook no argument.

Comment: A more appropriate way to pronounce it would be "Oh Ess Ten."

Comment: You're probably right... however, I'll probably continue to call it "oss ex" forevermore ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of Apple milestone OS releases for Macintosh systems. Note the numbering.

- System 1
- System 2
- System 3
- System 4
- System 5
- System 6
- System 7
- System/Mac OS 8
- Mac OS 9
- Mac OS X Server
- Mac OS X Public Beta
- Mac OS X 10.0 Cheetah
- Mac OS X 10.1 Puma
- Mac OS X 10.2 Jaguar
- Mac OS X 10.3 Panther
- Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger
- Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard
- Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard
- OS X 10.7 Lion
- OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
- OS X 10.9 Mavericks
- OS X 10.10 Yosemite *(unreleased)*

After 10.10, there will either be 10.11, or 11, or something completely different.

The OS releases began with 1, and have progressed to 10. Because the base system of Mac OS X 10.0 Cheetah (darwin, etc) remains relatively similar to the current day base system, this is why I believe that the numbering of (Mac)OS X systems have been point-based.

Comment: These are not all of the major versions and some are very minor i.e. several of System 7 are major and the OSX Server and Public a re minor - also does not explain why

Comment: Perhaps I should have named the list "Milestone OSes". I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Who down voted this? I think this is the best answer of the ones here!!!

Comment: What I mean is that 7.6 and one other of the 7s at least are both equal to a 10.x release

Comment: I understand that Mark, but it's not entirely relevant here. The question asked why OS X is consistently prefixed with 10. By providing a brief (and not entirely complete) history, I am able to provide an answer.